# Distributed FS with deterministic multiple masters?

Tags: distributed, database-replication, sharding

I'm looking for a distributed file (or other storage) system for managing a very large number of mutable documents. Each document can be rather large (1-100MB). Some reads need to be guaranteed to be working from the latest data, and some can be read from eventually-consistent replicated data. Each document could be a self-contained file (say, a SQLite database or other custom file format).

For optimal performance, the node of the distributed file system on which writes happen for each document must be different. In other words, server A is the master for document 1 and server B is replicating it, but server B is the master for document 2 and server A is replicating it. For my application, a single server is not going to be able to handle all of the write traffic for the whole system, so having a single master for all data is not acceptable.

Each document should be replicated across some number of servers (say, 3). So if I have 1000 documents and 10 servers, each server would have a copy of 300 documents, and be the master for 100 of those. Ideally, the cluster would automatically promote servers to be masters for documents whose master server had crashed, and re-balance the storage load as new servers are added to the cluster.

I realize this is a pretty tall order... is there something available that meets most of my core needs?

Answer (score 0):

I think [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hdfs_design.html#NameNode+and+DataNodes) would fit the criteria you listed above.